# Log in user with hashed password doesn't work on client side ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, authentication, hash, bcrypt

I'm working on a asp.net core web application and i've managed to register users and hash their passwords with the becrypt.net package, when saving them to the database.

I've trouble to figure out how to log in a user beacuse, of course, the passwords doesn't match.
Is their any way to check the hash on the client side when a user trying to log in?

[image]

Comment: You don't compare the password directly to the hash.  Instead, you hash whatever the user entered and compare the hash values.  This should be done on the server side only.  Don't trust that the hash comparison was successful if told by the client.

Comment: Okey! That may be the problem. Trying to do this on both server and client side.